# how do i add margin programmatically for TextView or even TableRow for android-based app?

Tags: android, textview, margin, tablelayout

hi i've tried to add margin programmatically

i've tried using

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(100, 20, 0, 0);
layout.addView(tv, params);
```

which uses android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams, but because of the table, i got runtime error for it.

how should i do it then ?

this is my code :

```
//create table row
TableRow trA = new TableRow(this);
        trA.setId(1000+i);
        trA.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams (LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        //add data to table row
        TextView tvA = new TextView (this);
        tvA.setId(2000+i);
        tvA.setText(aList.get(i).toString());
        tvA.setTextSize(18);
        tvA.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        tvA.setClickable(true);
        tvA.setOnClickListener(this);
        tvA.setSingleLine(false);
        tvA.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
        tvA.setWidth(0);
        tvA.setHeight(100);

        trA.addView(tvA);
        tableA.addView(trA,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

== edited with import android.widget.TableLayout.LayoutParams; ==

i added this at the end where i declare the tablerow

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams (LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 20);
```

and edited the addView at tableA

```
tableA.addView(tvA, params);
```

i have error in the log cat, it display quite alot, so i gave the main one here : The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: What is the runtime exception? Please post the stack trace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(100, 20, 0, 0);
```

Comment: sorry... i realised the problem is that i added the TextView to the table rather then the TableRow itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [`TableRow.LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.LayoutParams.html) instead.

So change your import to

```
import android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams
```